# join 2 files with different number of rows Part 2 with awk

Tags: awk

Good morning

I got 2 files and I want to join them.

I am using awk but I can use other command in bash. the problem is that when I try to awk some records that are not in both files do not appear in the final file.

file1

```
DDBB,size,PATH
stream,0,/databases/stream/ambit
stream,10,/databases/stream/tables_pks
stream,100,/databases/stream/scenario
stream,200,/databases/stream/selection
stream,3000,/databases/stream/election_block
aroa_bi,4000,/databases/aroa_bi/selection_filter
aroa_bi,10000,/databases/aroa_bi/validity
stream,50,/databases/stream/alidity_t
arquitectura_test,60,/databases/arquitectura_test/3a_backfilling_competitor_company_basket
arquitectura_prod,18000,/databases/arquitectura_prod/3a_backfilling_competitor_company_family
```

file2

```
DOMAIN,DDBB
mm,stream
aroa,aroa_bi
arquitectura,arquitectura_test
arquitectura,arquitectura_prod
```

And I wish:

file3

```
PATH,DOMAIN,size
/databases/stream/ambit,mm,0
/databases/stream/tables_pks,mm,10
/databases/stream/scenario,mm,100
/databases/stream/selection,mm,200
/databases/stream/election_block,mm,3000
/databases/aroa_bi/selection_filter,aroa,4000
/databases/aroa_bi/validity,aroa,10000
/databases/stream/alidity_t,mm,50
/databases/arquitectura_test/basket,arquitectura,60
/databases/arquitectura_prod/family,arquitectura,18000
```

Is a join as primary-key the *DDBB*

I am usinf¡g this code in awk but I can't find the way to work.

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }

NR==FNR { gsub(" ","",$1)                        # strip blanks from field #2
          a[$1]=$2
          next
        }

        { $1 = ($1 == "") ? "Unknown " : $1      # if file2.field#1 is missing then set to "Unknown"
          print a[$3],$1,a[$2]+0
          delete a[$2]                           # delete file1 entry so we do not print again in the END{} block
        }

END     { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"   # any entries leftover from file1 (ie, no matches) then sort by value and ...
          for (i in a)
              print "NewFiles",a[i]              # print to stdout
        }
' file1 file2 >file3

And I don't know where is the error

Thank in advantage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    map[$2] = $1
    next
}
{ print $3, map[$1], $2 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
PATH,DOMAIN,size
/databases/stream/ambit,mm,0
/databases/stream/tables_pks,mm,10
/databases/stream/scenario,mm,100
/databases/stream/selection,mm,200
/databases/stream/election_block,mm,3000
/databases/aroa_bi/selection_filter,aroa,4000
/databases/aroa_bi/validity,aroa,10000
/databases/stream/alidity_t,mm,50
/databases/arquitectura_test/3a_backfilling_competitor_company_basket,arquitectura,60
/databases/arquitectura_prod/3a_backfilling_competitor_company_family,arquitectura,18000
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using (g)awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm 72660398.db
sqlite3 72660398.db <<FILE1
CREATE TABLE file1(
   DDBB VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL
  ,size INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PATH VARCHAR(69) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('stream',0,'/databases/stream/ambit');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('stream',10,'/databases/stream/tables_pks');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('stream',100,'/databases/stream/scenario');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('stream',200,'/databases/stream/selection');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('stream',3000,'/databases/stream/election_block');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('aroa_bi',4000,'/databases/aroa_bi/selection_filter');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('aroa_bi',10000,'/databases/aroa_bi/validity');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('stream',50,'/databases/stream/alidity_t');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('arquitectura_test',60,'/databases/arquitectura_test/3a_backfilling_competitor_company_basket');
INSERT INTO file1(DDBB,size,PATH) VALUES ('arquitectura_prod',18000,'/databases/arquitectura_prod/3a_backfilling_competitor_company_family');
FILE1

sqlite3 72660398.db <<FILE2
CREATE TABLE file2(
   DOMAIN VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
  ,DDBB   VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO file2(DOMAIN,DDBB) VALUES ('mm','stream');
INSERT INTO file2(DOMAIN,DDBB) VALUES ('aroa','aroa_bi');
INSERT INTO file2(DOMAIN,DDBB) VALUES ('arquitectura','arquitectura_test');
INSERT INTO file2(DOMAIN,DDBB) VALUES ('arquitectura','arquitectura_prod');
FILE2

sqlite3 72660398.db <<FILE3
.mode csv
select file1.path,file2.DOMAIN,file1.size
from file1
inner join file2 on file2.DDBB = file1.DDBB;
FILE3
```

This is just because of your note: "I am using awk but I can use other command in bash"

PS. The name of the database used is derived from the (SO)question number.